# Consulta complicada

Tags: sql

Tengo esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta otra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es un query de consulta, que me muestre todos los *tipos de pago* y en otra columna *los pagos* seleccionados por el *idaliado*.

Resultado esperado:

[image: Esto es lo que necesito]

Se me ha complicado hacer un query que me muestre eso mismo, que solo muestre *los pagos* seleccionados por el *idaliado*, pero a la vez muestre el resto de *los pagos*

Este es el query que he usado

```
SELECT a.idpago, 
       a.pago, 
       case when b.idpago is null then 0 else 1 end as pos 
from tbltipospagos a 
    left join misformaspagos b on a.idpago = b.idpago 
where b.idaliado = 1 
   or b.idaliado is null
```

Comment: No termino de entender le problema ¿puedes explicarlo mejor?

Comment: ¿Que estaría faltando en la query que has hecho?  Pareciera que cumple con lo solictado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu consulta está muy cerca de ser correcta, pero la condición sobre la tabla `misformaspagos` debe de ir en el `JOIN` y no en el `WHERE`. De esa forma, la tabla solo usa las filas que necesitas.

```
SELECT a.idpago, 
       a.pago, 
       case when b.idpago is null then 0 else 1 end as pagoseleccionado,
       b.idaliado
from tbltipospagos a 
    left join misformaspagos b on a.idpago = b.idpago 
                              and b.idaliado = 1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ese si me funcionó no lo había intentado así.